# Configuring github to use local username and email for one project?

Tags: git, github

In my github I set up my github username as follows (name and email changed for privacy)

```
$ git config --global user.name "Work"
$ git config --global user.email work@work.com
```

Which has worked fine for me until now, where I want to make a project that is stored under a different github account since it is hobby related instead of work related. I tried to set up local values for username and password like so

```
$ git config --local user.name "Hobby"
$ git config --local user.email hobby@hobby.com
```

And I can see these values in my git config file. But when I try to push to my github account using `git push -u origin main` I get the following error `Permission to Hobby/project.git denied to Work` so it seems like when I am trying to push to my github it is using the global values for name and email instead of the local ones. Is there a way to get around this without removing my global variables entirely? I would like to keep the global values everywhere except this one specific project.

Comment: `user.name` is for committing. For pushing/pulling, look at your credential manager and your remote configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Git configuration of user.name and user.email has nothing to do with the permission error. You can specify any email and username. Those two values goes only into the commit author information.

The real issue that you are facing is that you need two different github accounts. Your machine caches the first github account and uses that one to authenticate against the repository where the cached credentials does not have access permissions.

There are two possible solutions to face this issue:

- Use SSH keys and clone the repositories using ssh
- Grant the other account access to the non working repository

I would prefer the first one.

Comment: Thank you I was confused as to what user.name and user.email do exactly. I've managed to set up with SSH keys now

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with below commands,

```
git config --local credential.helper ""
git push origin master
```

It asks for username and password for current repo.